# Xtrafinder dual pane view disappeared

Tags: finder

I just got a new MAC (my first one) and already screwed up something :P
Basically I installed Xtrafinder, mainly to have the dual pane feature that I find quite essential.
I launched Finder with the new add-on and the dual pane was there and working nicely.

Afterwards, I decided that the list view is the one I love the most, and tried to get that as default view.

I managed to find a solution using the command

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder FXPreferredViewStyle Nlsv
```

followed by

```
killall Finder
```

Now I do have a default list view of all my files and folder; the problem is that the dual pane view has mysteriously disappeared. I think I've checked all the preferences of both Finder and Xtrafinder and I couldn't find anything to restore it :/

Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: For some weird reason, there is some mechanism deleting the initial string "Hello folks," I had placed at the beginning of the message :/

Comment: Yes, introductions are removed automatically from posts; [this is by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Welcome to Ask Different!